# how to get the values from the below to string?

Tags: java

How do I get the values from this array list to string. I need to know about that now to use my program.

```
JSONFunctions a=new JSONFunctions();
jsonarray= a.getJSONfromURL(URL);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
JSONFunctions a=new JSONFunctions();
jsonarray= a.getJSONfromURL(URL);

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
    {
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       JSONObject js=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
       map.put("artid",js.getString("artid"));
       map.put("arttitle",js.getString("arttitle"));
       map.put("artdescription",js.getString("artdescrption"));
       map.put("artimage", js.getString("artimage"));
       map.put("artdate",js.getString("artdate"));
       arraylist.add(map);
    }
} 
catch (JSONException e)
{
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Values of the list is a `HashMap<String, String>`, so you can't store it in `String`. If you are actually talking about getting values from `HashMap`, then what value you want to get? Is there any condition, on which you want to fetch the value. And finally, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an arraylist of hashmaps, you should do something like:

```
String s = arraylist.get(someindex).get("somestring");
```

If you provide further details, we will be able to help you more.

Comment: It's not an array. Look again.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've created a list of HashMaps. I wonder what could have been such a requirement.

Anyways, here's how to iterate over this arraylist.

i. Iterate over the arraylist

ii. You'll get a HashMap as you iterate

iii. Iterate over this HashMap within the above iteration.

```
for(HashMap<String,String> hMap:arrayList){
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()){
         String key=entry.getKey();
         String value=entry.getKey();
         //...Do what you require
    }
}
```